# SQL "deduplicate" using NULL as a wildcard

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Consider the following table, where none of the columns have a `NULL` constraint:

```
  a   |  b   |  c   |  d
------+------+------+------
    3 |    5 |   12 | NULL
 NULL |    5 |   12 | NULL
   13 | NULL |   26 | NULL
 NULL | NULL |   26 |    4
    6 |    7 |    5 | NULL
    6 | NULL | NULL | NULL
    6 | NULL |    5 | NULL
    6 |    7 | NULL | NULL
 NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
(9 rows)
```

All nine rows are distinct, but if we take `NULL` to be a "wildcard," meaning that it can take on any value, then only the first, third, fourth, and fifth rows are surely distinct. Since the non-null values of the other rows all appear in the surely distinct rows, I would like to drop these rows to yield the following table:

```
  a   |  b   | c  |  d
------+------+----+------
    3 |    5 | 12 | NULL
   13 | NULL | 26 | NULL
 NULL | NULL | 26 |    4
    6 |    7 |  5 | NULL
(4 rows)
```

In a given table, how does one delete rows whose values represent a subset of the values of another row in the same table? Another way of asking this question is, how does one deduplicate a table using `NULL` as a wildcard?

Don't worry about deleting actual duplicate rows (which is why I put "deduplicate" in quotes in the title). In particular, I would like to be able to do this in both PostgreSQL and Redshift.

For reference, these statements create the original table described above:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a int, b int, c int, d int);
INSERT INTO t
VALUES (   3,    5,   12, NULL),
       (NULL,    5,   12, NULL),
       (  13, NULL,   26, NULL),
       (NULL, NULL,   26,    4),
       (   6,    7,    5, NULL),
       (   6, NULL, NULL, NULL),
       (   6, NULL,    5, NULL),
       (   6,    7, NULL, NULL),
       (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: how many columns are there?

Comment: It would help to know what the columns mean.  Better sample data would help.  Could `a` have `NULL` values?  Could there be different non-NULL values in each column?  If so, how would these be combined?  If you had two identical rows with `NULL` values, would one be dropped?  Or are only fully "resolved" rows kept?

Comment: I'm looking for a general answer, so in principle the number and meanings of the columns should be irrelevant.

If it helps, suppose there are four columns, each of which holds product identifiers for a different vendor, and the `NULL`s represent missing data. In this case, knowing that `(2, NULL, 35, 52)` appears in our table isn't as helpful as knowing that `(2, 18, 35, 52)` appears, so we want to drop the former and keep the latter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any column could have `NULL` values. There could indeed be different non-`NULL` values in each column. We want to run a `DISTINCT` operation that treats `NULL` as a wildcard, so we would not combine column values. If you have two identical rows with `NULL` values, then we want the resulting table to have just one of those rows (any which one). If by "fully resolved," you mean that a row doesn't have any `NULL`s, then we want to keep both fully resolved rows and rows that contain `NULL`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail to detect true duplicates (catches both), I think we still need the `ctid` (or some cursor-stuff)

---

```
WITH enums AS (
        SELECT x.a, x.b,x.c,x.d
        -- , (x.a IS NULL)::integer + (x.b IS NULL)::integer 
         -- + (x.c IS NULL)::integer + (x.d IS NULL)::integer AS nnull
        , row_number() OVER www AS rn
        FROM tbl x
        JOIN tbl y
        ON (x.a =y.a OR x.a IS NULL)
        AND (x.b =y.b OR x.b IS NULL)
        AND (x.c =y.c OR x.c IS NULL)
        AND (x.d =y.d OR x.d IS NULL)
        WINDOW WWW AS
        (PARTITION BY COALESCE(x.a ,y.a), COALESCE(x.b ,y.b)
                , COALESCE(x.c ,y.c), COALESCE(x.d ,y.d)
         ORDER BY x.a NULLS LAST
        , x.b NULLS LAST
        , x.c NULLS LAST
        , x.d NULLS LAST )
        )
SELECT* --DELETE
-- FROM  enums ex ; \q
FROM tbl del
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM  enums ex
        WHERE ex.rn > 1
        AND ex.a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM del.a
        AND ex.b IS NOT DISTINCT FROM del.b
        AND ex.c IS NOT DISTINCT FROM del.c
        AND ex.d IS NOT DISTINCT FROM del.d
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

To only select those without a match based on the NULL wildcards.
Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM T AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T AS dup
    WHERE (dup.a = t.a OR t.a IS NULL)
      AND (dup.b = t.b OR t.b IS NULL)
      AND (dup.c = t.c OR t.c IS NULL)
      AND (dup.d = t.d OR t.d IS NULL)
      AND CONCAT(dup.a,'-',dup.b,'-',dup.c,'-',dup.d) <> CONCAT(t.a,'-',t.b,'-',t.c,'-',t.d)
)
```

To only select the duplicates based on the NULL wildcards.
Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM T AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T AS dup
    WHERE (dup.a = t.a OR t.a IS NULL)
      AND (dup.b = t.b OR t.b IS NULL)
      AND (dup.c = t.c OR t.c IS NULL)
      AND (dup.d = t.d OR t.d IS NULL)
      AND CONCAT(dup.a,'-',dup.b,'-',dup.c,'-',dup.d) <> CONCAT(t.a,'-',t.b,'-',t.c,'-',t.d)
)
```

To delete the dups from the table, based on the NULL wildcards.
Using EXISTS:

```
DELETE
FROM T AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T AS dup
    WHERE (dup.a = t.a OR t.a IS NULL)
      AND (dup.b = t.b OR t.b IS NULL)
      AND (dup.c = t.c OR t.c IS NULL)
      AND (dup.d = t.d OR t.d IS NULL)
      AND CONCAT(dup.a,'-',dup.b,'-',dup.c,'-',dup.d) <> CONCAT(t.a,'-',t.b,'-',t.c,'-',t.d)
)
```

Do note that because of the compare on the CONCAT, that records which have an exact duplicate won't be seen as dups.

If the table has an ID as primary key, then the compare of the CONCAT's could be replaced by

```
AND dup.ID <> t.ID
```

But then those with an exact duplicate would also both be seen as dups.

Comment: This worked on my original 3-row example (i.e., `[(2, NULL, 35, 52), (1, 17, 34, NULL), (2, 18, 35, 52)]`), but it fails for the 9-row example I later edited into the question.

Comment: @aparkerlue Adapted for the 9-row example.

Answer (score 1):

FYI

Someone posted a pretty tidy answer shortly after I asked my question, but it looks like he/she later deleted it. The code in the answer didn't quite work, but I liked the approach. I've modified it, and it seems to do the job:

```
DELETE FROM t
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT u.*
     FROM t AS u
    WHERE (t.a IS NULL OR t.a = u.a)
      AND (t.b IS NULL OR t.b = u.b)
      AND (t.c IS NULL OR t.c = u.c)
      AND (t.d IS NULL OR t.d = u.d)
      AND NOT (
        (
          t.a IS NULL AND u.a IS NULL
          OR (
            t.a IS NOT NULL AND u.a IS NOT NULL
            AND t.a = u.a
          )
        )
        AND (
          t.b IS NULL AND u.b IS NULL
          OR (
            t.b IS NOT NULL AND u.b IS NOT NULL
            AND t.b = u.b
          )
        )
        AND (
          t.c IS NULL AND u.c IS NULL
          OR (
            t.c IS NOT NULL AND u.c IS NOT NULL
            AND t.c = u.c
          )
        )
        AND (
          t.d IS NULL AND u.d IS NULL
          OR (
            t.d IS NOT NULL AND u.d IS NOT NULL
            AND t.d = u.d
          )
        )
      )
 );
```

A more concise version that is not (yet) supported on Redshift:

```
DELETE FROM t
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT u.*
     FROM t AS u
    WHERE (t.a IS NULL OR t.a = u.a)
      AND (t.b IS NULL OR t.b = u.b)
      AND (t.c IS NULL OR t.c = u.c)
      AND (t.d IS NULL OR t.d = u.d)
          EXCEPT
   SELECT t.*
 );
```

Comment: To be honest, I somehow can't get my head around why this even works O_o  The except is supposed to remove all lines that are in T from a selection on T.  How come there still EXIST after that filtering. But it works somehow.  Odd... Almost a SQL hack.

Comment: @LukStorms I think the `t.*` in the subquery refers to just one row, since the subquery is evaluated once for each row in `t`.

Comment: This doesn't work in Redshift: `ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet`.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I tested that on PostGreSQL and MS SQL Server. On those it worked.  Because I was curious if this was just a special quirk of the EXCEPT in PostGreSQL, But if it also works on SQL Server there might be more to it.  Heh, the error adds the word "yet".

Answer (score 0):

This will find unique rows with wild cards (nulls), but it might not work if there are more than 1 null per match.

This works by first getting rows with without nulls, and joining it back to the base table and filling the nulls. finally, selecting distinct yields the desired result.

```
WITH nn AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM t 
    WHERE a IS NOT NULL 
      AND b IS NOT NULL 
      AND c IS NOT NULL 
      AND d IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
      COALESCE(t1.a, nn.a) a
    , COALESCE(t1.b, nn.b) b
    , COALESCE(t1.c, nn.c) c
    , COALESCE(t1.d, nn.d) d
    FROM t t1 
    LEFT JOIN nn
           ON (t1.a IS NULL OR t1.a = nn.a)
          AND (t1.b IS NULL OR t1.b = nn.b)
          AND (t1.c IS NULL OR t1.c = nn.c)
          AND (t1.d IS NULL OR t1.d = nn.d)
```

For example, this won't work if two additional rows are inserted:

```
insert into t values (2, 10, 12, null), (2, null, 12, 10);
```

because the cte of not-nulls (nn) omits both.

Comment: A had a similar solution. For real duplicates we stil lneed the ctid/rowid, though.

Comment: This worked on my original 3-row example (i.e., `[(2, NULL, 35, 52), (1, 17, 34, NULL), (2, 18, 35, 52)]`), but it fails for the 9-row example I later edited into the question.